# Creating a break between prompts with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, break, prompt, multiplication

So basically I'm trying to make it so the webpage will continually prompt you to enter a number until you enter *-1*. Then, it will stop and post multiplication tables of all the previous numbers you entered.

This is what I have so far and I'm really not sure where to go from here.

```
<script>
    var num = prompt("Enter Number", "0")

    var num = parseInt(num);
    var i = 0;

    document.write('<table ="1">');
    for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        document.write("<tr><td>" + num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i + "</td></tr>");
    }

    document.write("</table>");

    var num = prompt("Enter Number", "0")

    document.write('<table ="1">');
    for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        document.write("<tr><td>" + num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i + "</td></tr>");
    }

    document.write("</table>");

    var num = prompt("Enter Number", "0")

    document.write('<table ="1">');
    for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        document.write("<tr><td>" + num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i + "</td></tr>");
    }

    document.write("</table>");


</script>
```

Comment: A `while` loop will be your friend here.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [do...while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) loop. The code below also uses [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create DOM elements, [document.createTextNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) and [Node.appendchild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add them to a container element instead of using [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var num;
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  do {
    num = prompt("Enter Number", "0");
    if (num > 0) {
      var table = document.createElement('table');
      for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i));
        row.appendChild(cell);
        table.appendChild(row);
      }
      container.appendChild(table);
    }
  } while (num > 0);
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the previous post, simply commented to heck and gone. And yeah, avoid document.write -- that was great in books from the early 2000's, but it is outdated and in many cases will break. I also assumed, when you say multiplication tables, that you want to iterate over the input number and create a full table to that number. Thus, the two inner loops: one for the input number and one for up to twelve iterations.

Good luck on this school assignment!

```js
var num = 0, total = 0;

num = parseInt(prompt("Enter Number or -1 to end", 0));
// Keep doing this loop until -1 is entered.
while (num != -1){
// Create a table element, but don't add it yet.
var myTable = document.createElement("table");
  // This line loops to the prompted number...
  for (var i=0; i<=num; i++){
    // ... and creates each ROW of the table  
    var myTr = document.createElement("tr");
    // this line loops for 12 iterations..
    for (var j=0; j<13; j++){
      // and creates and adds each TD element to the current row
      var myTd = document.createElement("td");
      myTd.innerHTML = j+" * "+i+" = "+j*i;
      myTr.appendChild(myTd);
    }
    // Having added all the TDs to the row, we add the row to the table
    myTable.appendChild(myTr);
  }
  // Having added all the rows to the table, we can add the table to the document!
document.body.appendChild(myTable);
// And now ask for another number to make another table, either starting
//   the loop again or breaking out.
num = parseInt(prompt("Enter Number or -1 to end", "0"));
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```